# tikz - text not aligned vertically and how to center text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

You can see in the figure that the text "Reconstruction" and "Forecasting" are not vertically aligned. How do I fix that? Also, is it possible to have the text be centered between the figures? In powerpoint, I would create a text box of the same length then center the text in it. How do I do that here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}

    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image1.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image3.north east);
    \node[anchor=south west, fill=white] at ([xshift=0.70cm,yshift=0.15cm]image1.north west) {Reconstruction};
    
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image4.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image8.north east);
    \node[anchor=south west, fill=white] at ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=0.15cm]image4.north west) {Forecasting};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fist question (vertical alignment), add a `\strut` to the texts, this way both of them will have the same height. For the second one, place the texts in a node `midway` path.

Also, I don't think you need the `scope` in the last `tikzpicture`, and if you don't want separate captions it probably would be better to place all in the same `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image1.north west) --
                            ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image3.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image4.north west) --
                            ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image8.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Forecasting};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** if you don't separate captions you could do something like this (the output is almost the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]\centering
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\sep{0.5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node              (image1) at (0,0)                      {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image2) at ([xshift=\sep]image1.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image3) at ([xshift=\sep]image2.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image4) at ([xshift=\sep]image3.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image5) at ([xshift=\sep]image4.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image6) at ([xshift=\sep]image5.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image7) at ([xshift=\sep]image6.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=west] (image8) at ([xshift=\sep]image7.east) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift= 0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image1.north west) --
                          ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image3.north east) node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};
  \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift= 0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image4.north west) --
                          ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]image8.north east) node[midway,above] {\strut Forecasting};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear:

- why you use `\subfloat` for each image? Will each have their own caption?
- Are acceptable to draw images without `subfloat`s?

In MWE below all images or in one `tikzpicture`. For positioning of nodes with images is used `chains` library. Image with is determined by `\setkeys{Gin}{...}`, By both measures code is quite shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}      % loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.12\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1mm and 1mm,
      start chain = going right,
       arr/.style = {thick, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm},
every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer ysep=2mm, on chain}
                    ]
    \node (n1)  {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node       {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node (n3)  {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node (n4)  {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node       {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node       {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node (n7)  {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
\draw[arr]  (n1.north west) -- node[above] {Reconstruction}    (n3.north east);
\draw[arr]  (n4.north west) -- node[above] {Forecasting}    (n7.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]